# Overlapping Isotope images when adding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope, image-gallery

I have been struggling to get [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to work. I have an application where after clicking a button I load some more images by getting their URLs from JSON. The issue I am having is that when I add the images to the 'galleryContainer' div (my div that I am holding all the images in) the images overlap. That or nothing happens and the whole page seems to freeze. Apparently this is a [frequent problem](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html) but I still have not been able to get it working for my project. I try to use 'imagesLoaded' but it never seems to work for me.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Get more images and add them to the galleryContainer
function getMoreImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newImage = $('<div class="objects"></div>');
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 750);
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 750);      

    newImage.append($('<img width="750" src="http://lorempixel.com/' + x + '/' + y + '">'));
    $container.append(newImage).imagesLoaded(function() {
      $container.isotope('appended', newImage);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a (JSFiddle)[http://codepen.io/dirtshell/pen/emdjGv] demonstrating my problem.

It is totally possible that I am simply making a simple mistake JS wise (like not using the imagesLoaded plugin correctly), since I am sort of new to it.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that your codepen is using isotope v2 but your js and CSS are for isotope v1.5.
You need imagesLoaded to prevent the overlap  but it is not included as part of isotope v2 as it was in v1.5. You need to load it separately. 
Is the  getMoreImages() function what you are actually using on your site to load new images? 
Also there is no longer "animationOptions" in isotope v2:

This

```
 animationOptions: {
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }
```

is now this:

```
transitionDuration: '0.4s'
```

and in v2, you can remove any v1.5 isotope CSS

**ADDENDUM**

Here is an update to you [Codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/emBNaN)

here is the relevant code (altered):

```
var $container = $('.galleryContainer');

// Initialize isotope on window load and image load
$(window).load(function() {
$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.objects',
  masonry: {
  columnWidth: 780
},
  transitionData: '0.4s'
});
});

 // Get more images and add them to the galleryContainer
 $('.loadButton').on( 'click', function() { 
 var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 750);
 var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 750); 
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 var newImage = $('<div class="objects"><img width="750" src="http://lorempixel.com/' + x + '/' + y + '"></div>');  
  }

 $container.append(newImage).imagesLoaded(function() {
  $container.isotope('appended', newImage);
 });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks I changed the CSS and the initialization of Isotope. I then loaded imagesLoaded() as an external resource, and then used it as shown in the FAQ. However, now when I load more images on the [codepen](http://codepen.io/dirtshell/pen/emdjGv/), it lays everything out weird, with large spaces between the images. And yes, the getMoreImages() function is what I am actually using on the site. When I did it in a batch of jQuery elements I was not able to get things working =(

Comment: Thanks, this was the lead I needed. I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier, but this helped and I was able to get things working.